# How to prevent iframe from showing element with special classname?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am currently trying to show a matomo dashboard inside an iframe for my customers. There are some elements in the iframe i don't want to show.

This is what I tried:

```js
function removeSegmentedLog(){
    var segmentedlog = document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName('actionSegmentVisitorLog');
    console.log(segmentedlog);
    for (let j = 0; j <= segmentedlog.length; j++) {
        document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName('actionSegmentVisitorLog')[j].remove();
        console.log('remove');
    }
}
```

The function is called at onload of the iframe element.

The console sometimes says there are no elements, but they are there.

Is there any way to prevent the iframe from showing any Elements with classname 'actionSegmentVisitorLog' ?

Comment: A thing that comes to mind is that the iframe's onload fires once the DOM is loaded, but the actual elements you're after could be added via JS asynchronously. You could add a timeOut inside your onload function and see if that changes the behavior.

Comment: If you don’t need the elements actually removed from the DOM, but only to be hidden - then inserting a little stylesheet into the iframe, that contains just something like `.actionSegmentVisitorLog { display: none !important; }`, might be easier.